# Save canvasJS charts to server directory

Tags: javascript, php, export, canvasjs

How could I save an exported canvasJS chart into server side directory using PHP?

There is no problem when creating a pie chart, making it exportable and exporting it directly using the built-in js function:

```
function ajaxGrafTarta(llamada,titulo){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard.php",
        data: {
            llamada: llamada
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(llamada, {
                animationEnabled: true,
                exportEnabled: true,
                exportFileName: llamada,
                title: {
                    text: titulo
                },
                data: [{
                    type: "pie",
                    startAngle: -90,
                    yValueFormatString: "#,##0.00\"%\"",
                    indexLabel: "{label} ({y})",
                    dataPoints: data
                }]
            });
            chart.render();

            chart.exportChart({format: "jpg"});
        }
    });
}
```

My aim is to save that js-created file into a directory in my server (i know js is client-side), is it any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem, I managed to solve it. I looped through all my canvases using `toDataURL()` JS function and then sending them via AJAX. I acomplished it firstly sending the image data in PNG format in my JS:

```
$("canvas").each(function() {
   var dataURL = ($(this)[0]).toDataURL("image/png");

   if(dataURL.indexOf("AAAAAAAA") == -1){
     var filename = $(this).parent().closest('.grafico').attr('id') + ".png";
     $.ajax({
        url: "guardar_graficos.php",
           data: {
               image: dataURL,
               filename: filename
               },
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "image/png"
            }); 
          }
      });
```

And then catching and saving it in the server side using PHP:

```
$upload_dir = "foo/";
$iid = $_POST['image'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$img_encode = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $iid);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img_encode);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir.$filename;
unlink($upload_dir.$filename);
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```